# How to correctly typeset subscripts after \varphi?

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

I'm using `$\Delta\varphi_R$` in several locations in my document, but the subscript has almost the same size and vertical position of the variable. Is there a way to make it look more like a subscript?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
$\Delta\varphi_R$
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Although `R` is slighly smaller than `\varphi`, they still look like they are on the same level and a bit too far away. Is there an easy way to fix it globally?

Comment: If it *means* something, then define a command.

Comment: By the way, what does it mean?

Comment: @Manuel You're right. I'll define a command and use the formatting in Christian's answer. It's the variable I'm using for "the relative slip angle" in a paper in German (Rutschwinkel)

Comment: In case `\Delta` is the increment, `\newcommand*\increment{\mathop{}\!\Delta}` (or may be just `\newcommand*\increment{\Delta}`) and then `\newcommand*\relativeslipangle{\increment\phi_{\scriptscriptstyle R}}`. Of course you may choose better names.

Comment: @Manuel Add a negative space before the subscript, and it works perfectly. Why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: I didn't know what you were referring to, so no good name came to my mind, and Christian's answer is basically the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm quite certain that the middle subformula in the following example is the correct one. The empty superscript pushes the subscript a bit lower.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
$\Delta\varphi_R\ne\Delta\varphi^{}_R\ne\Delta\varphi^{}_{\!R}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm also quite certain that using `_{\scriptscriptstyle R}` is wrong.

Comment: Is there a reason to avoid adding a negative space as in the third subformula? It looks better to me

Comment: @Timmy Not to me. `;-)` Be consistent, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's not necessarily wrong, so I wouldn't bother. However, if it *means* something as a whole I think defining an appropiate command is the way to go. Moreover, for this situation, it's perfect because that way we can include small adjustments inside that command in case we want.

In case `\Delta` means an increment, you should define a command:

```
\newcommand*\increment{\Delta}
```

That way everything is more readable `\increment\varphi_R`. However if that last one means something as a whole, then, there's no problem with defining a new command

```
\newcommand*\relativeslipangle{\increment\varphi_{R}}
```

And here it comes the trick, now that we have a command, we can take advantage of it and tweak it to our wish.

```
\newcommand*\relativeslipangle{\increment\varphi_{\scriptscriptstyle\!R}}
```

But, in case it were out of a command, we couldn't apply this trick, so I wouldn't bother and *wouldn't write explicitly `\varphi_{\scriptscriptstyle\!R}`, just `\varphi_R`*.

Comment: I followed your advice and created a new command, then used regex to replace it everywhere. I know it's better practice to define new commands, but I tend to forget

Comment: Not to save typing, but to write a more readable and more “correct” document. The example is `\increment` (or `\inc` or whatever name you choose), you keep using `\Delta` your whole document: then `\Delta` is not only one thing, but two; you can't search & replace, or even read code, easily; it's difficult to change the definition of “increment” when you have been using `\Delta`; and, forgotten or infravalued by many people, *it's “conceptually” wrong*.

Comment: I tried to write the whole process we should “ideally” pass to get to the point of changing the output a little bit: we need a definition because it's an entity, it means something; and then we take advantage of that by changing that command.